# How do I simplify this integer validation?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and I'm working on a method in my program that checks the users input to be within bounds, not a null value (zero), not a letter, and a positive number. So originally I incorporated two while loops within this method to check for the validity of these inputs, but I would like to simplify it in one loop. I'm getting an error when I input a letter (ex. a) after a few inputs, and I believe it is due to the two different while loops making it more complicated. Can someone help me with this please?

```
public static void valid(String s, int max) 
{ 
    while(sc.hasNextInt() == false) {
        System.out.println("That is not correct. Try again:");
        sc.nextLine();  

    }

    int value;
    while((value= sc.nextInt()) > max || (value= sc.nextInt()) <= 0){
        System.out.println("That is not correct. Try again: ");
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    sc.nextLine();
    return;

}
```

Comment: What error? Do you get *"That is not correct. Try again:"*  or some exception?

Comment: If you are using `nextInt`, you will never be able to read in a letter.

Comment: you also need to be using '==' in your second while loop. (value = sc.nextInt()) is not the same thing as (value == sc.nextInt()).

Comment: No, he does only use one equal in the second loop. He is assigning the value of `sc.nextInt()` to `value` and then checking to see if it is greater than max. However, the second part of the while loop is the issue. It should just say `|| value <= 0`

Comment: @blahfunk I tried this and this error showed: "Syntax error, insert ") Statement" to complete WhileStatement"

Comment: @Gendarme currently it is skipping two inputs, for ex: it asks to enter an input, so i enter 1, it gives no response, so i enter 1 again, and then the program takes it

Comment: @OFakos That is addressed in the first part of my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36846116/5221346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
int value;
    while((value= sc.nextInt()) > max || (value= sc.nextInt()) <= 0){
        System.out.println("That is not correct. Try again: ");
        sc.nextLine();
    }
```

Which is doing `sc.nextInt()` twice, so `value` does not necessarily have the same value in these two cases and it is also asking you for a number twice.

A fix would be something like this:

```
int value;
    while((value = sc.nextInt()) > max || value <= 0) {
        System.out.println("That is not correct. Try again: ");
        sc.nextLine();
    }
```

which would make it better but you still have issues. If `value` is bigger than `max`, then the loop will iterate again calling `nextInt()` but this time you have *not* checked for `hasNextInt()`. This is why you'd better have everything in one loop. Something like this:

```
public static void valid(String s, int max) { 
    while(true) {
        if(!sc.hasNextInt()) { //this is the same as sc.hasNextInt() == false
            System.out.println("That is not correct. Try again:");
            sc.nextLine();
            continue; //restart the loop again
        } else {
            int value = sc.nextInt();
            if(value > max || value <= 0) {
                System.out.println("That is not correct. Try again:");
                sc.nextLine();
                continue; //restart the loop from the top - important!
            } else {
                extendedValidation(value, s);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something more like (pseudo code):

```
while valid input not yet received:
    if input is an integer:
        get integer
        if in range:
            set valid input received
    skip rest of line

extended validation
```

With a little thought, you should be able use one "print error message" statement.  But using two could be arguably better; it can tell the user what they did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the `String s` parameter? Should you be checking that instead of a Scanner input?

Also, don't be surprised by mixing `nextInt()` and `nextLine()`. -- [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

I prefer using do-while loops for input before validation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int max = 1000;
    int val = -1;
    String in;

    do {
        // Read a string
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        in = input.nextLine();

        // check for a number
        try {
            val = Integer.parseInt(in);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            // ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("That is not correct. Try again.");
            continue;
        }

        // check your bounds
        if (val <= 0 || val > max) {
            System.out.println("That is not correct. Try again.");
            continue;
        } else {
            break; // exit loop when valid input
        }

    } while (true);

    System.out.println("You entered " + val);
    // extendedValidation(value, in);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is a lot closer to what you're looking for, in simple terms...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int MIN = 0;
        final int MAX = 10;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value = -1;
        boolean valid;

        do {
            valid = sc.hasNextInt();
            if (valid) {
                value = sc.nextInt();
                valid = value > MIN && value < MAX;
            }

            if (!valid) {
                System.out.println("Invalid!");
                sc.nextLine();
            }
        } while (!valid);

        System.out.println("Valid Value: " + value);
    }
}
```

You should be able to abstract this code to suit your requirements.